# HTML global variables

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out how global variables are defined in HTML.

I have noticed on a lot of webpages that the hyperlinks are not fully written out. Only their suffix is written in the HTML with the global variable hyperlink hidden from view.

For example:

https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/statistics/2010/dl20.cfm

```
  <li class="arrow"><a href="/policy/olsp/" title="Legislative Affairs &amp; Policy Communications"><span>Legislative Affairs &amp; Policy Communications</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/policy/olsp/what.cfm">What We Do</a></li>
      <li><a href="/policy/olsp/olspstaff.cfm">Staff Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="/policy/olsp/programareas.cfm">Program Areas</a></li>
      <li><a href="/policy/olsp/reportspubs.cfm">Surface Transportation Reauthorization</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Note how the links in the the above HTML does not have the global variable prefix.

`"https://www.fhwa.dot.gov"`

But only has the suffix link extention `"/policy/olsp/what.cfm"`

Yet when you click on the link it leads you to: "https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policy/olsp/what.cfm"

I know this may sound trivial. But how do I explicitly know every suffix link's prefix link?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: HTML has no variables. It is a markup language. All it does is describe a document layout. What you are actually looking at there is a relative path. That path is relative to the current document. Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#A_quick_primer_on_URLs_and_paths

Comment: RFC3986. See section 4.2, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2, and section 5, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5 (specifically 5.1, "Establishing a Base URI"). It's called a "relative reference". `href="/foo"` means "relative to the domain's root", so it means the same thing anywhere on the same domain. `href="foo"` means "relative to the root of the current folder", so it can point different places depending what URL you're currently on.

Answer (score 1):

They are root relative links, without the domain they are always based off of the root origin. You can find this in JS by reading `window.location.origin`.

You can read about some options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).